# Optimal partitioning

Tags: optimization, partitioning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9oQP.png)I'm looking for a way to perform optimal partitioning of the following: I have a square that is divided into a number of small equally-sized squares, say N and I need to group them into K groups so that the number of squares in the groups are almost equal. Cells in each group should be contiguous. In addition, the 2 dimensions of each group is almost equal. Is there any way to achieve this?

the image shows an example partitioning for N=72, K=4

Thank you for any help

Comment: Could you add a picture to demonstrate how such a partitioning would look like?

Comment: There are obviously troublesome cases, as k=3 for example. In these cases it will be very important to formalize your two conflicting objectives: number of squares of each group, dimensions of each group (which might collapse into two objectives). Which one is how important? Without a mathematical-model there is no *good* solution. It's also important how big N and K are. If N is not too big, brute-force seems doable.

Comment: Number of squares gets the first priority, and the dimensions is the second.